# Redirected to another page when carousel button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

When I click on the carousel left and right button, I am always directed to another page(login page). I am able to click on the small button to navigate to the other slides but not through the button. Im not sure why it turned out to be this way.

## app.js

```
        .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
    })
```

## index.html

```
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a>
        </li>
```

## home.html

```
    <section>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="/img/ibm.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="/img/ibm.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using `routing`?

Comment: share route code too;

Comment: sorry, i didn't use route for this @itzmukeshy7

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your JQuery file is loaded after your bootstrap file like this

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
```

It should be loading the JQuery first and than Bootstrap like this.

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Check this if this is not the case then will have to take a deeper look.

Also you may find some useful answers here

[Carousel Slider redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154610/carousel-slider-redirects-to-carousel-example-generic)